# Why does the keypad show strange entries on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

Why does the top of the keypad show an exorbitant amount of numbers when I press the paste button?

At the bottom are all the websites I visit.  I can get rid of them.
 
I have cleared everything and not signed into anything.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent Karen! Unfortunately your question is difficult to understand and might get closed if you don't clarify your problem. Could you please tell us where this is happening? Is it Safari? It would be wonderful if you add a [screenshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot#iOS) to your question.

Comment: When I'm in my phone# keypad, I press above the 2, hit paste and we pages show up  above that  are a series of ###s  random #s.  yes I use Safari.  But I'm just  wanting to use the phone to make a call  does this help anyone to help me ?  Can't screenshot.

Comment: Why can you not screenshot?  Just hold HOME and tap LOCK.

Comment: Also - just upload your screenshot to any website and link to the URL. We can embed things for you until you get enough reputation to inline images yourself.

Answer (score 5):

If you paste text, it translates the letters into numbers as represented on the keypad.  For example: `1800 BUY NOW` becomes `1800289669`

If you've copied text instead of just a number, or if you've copied a link behind a number, you might actually be pasting a web address like `http://www.apple.com` which is changed to `488799927753266` after stripping punctuation.

Go to the **Notes** app and paste there.  What is actually stored in the clipboard?